# how find max values using MySQL

Tags: mysql, vb.net

how to find max values ​​using MySQL as the database? examples in the database ID (primary key and AutoNumber) data that will come 12. so, in the form at the moment want to add data, automatic number 12 also

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for a query like this:

```
SELECT MAX(id) FROM table;
```